# Why "IsChecked" value from checkbox false?

Tags: wpf, linq, mvvm, data-binding

I am struggling for some time with binding a checkbox to some listbox values, specifically I don't know what is wrong with my binding.I have tried all different approaches, from read-only properties to delegate commands, even a separate class for the list box.The list box has values which are being saved by checking them using a checkbox.Now, in my last version, I thought of having two collections, one for all the courses taught and the other for the selected courses that a lecturer teaches.These are my 2 collections:

This is in the RegisterTeacherViewModel.cs:

```
private ObservableCollection<Cours> _courses;

public ObservableCollection<Cours> Courses
{
    get => _courses;
    set
    {
        _courses = value;
        NotifyOnPropertyChange(nameof(Courses));//this is the collection that holds all the courses.
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<Cours> selectedCourses;
public ObservableCollection<Cours> SelectedCourses
{
    get { return selectedCourses; }
    set
    {
        selectedCourses = value;
        NotifyOnPropertyChange("SelectedCourse");
    }
}//this is the collection for the selected courses.
```

Now I have a method where I have to store the selected courses along with other values that the lecturer is inserting in the XAML form.This is the method for storing the values:

```
public void SaveTeacher(object param)
{

    using (DatabaseStudentsEntitiesLastStand db = new 
    DatabaseStudentsEntitiesLastStand())
    {
        Cours c = new Cours();
        RegisterTeacher t = new RegisterTeacher();

        if(c.IsChecked==true)//here I am checking if the value "IsChecked" is true and if it is, then the course name will be stored in the DB
        {                 
            t.CourseName=courseName;
        }
        t.SNTeacher = SNTeacher;
        t.UserName = _UserName;
        t.pwd = pwd;
        t.fullName = fullName;
        t.education = education;

        db.RegisterTeachers.Attach(t);

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
    }
}
```

Now,I also have a delegate command both for the "save" button:

```
private DelegateCommand saveCommand;
public DelegateCommand SaveCommand
{
    get { return saveCommand; }
    set
    {
        if (saveCommand != value)
        {
            saveCommand = value;
            NotifyOnPropertyChange("SaveCommand");
        }
    }
}
```

And one command for the checkbox named CheckCommand:

```
public bool IsChecked
{
    get { return isChecked; }
    set
    {
        if(isChecked!=value)
        {
            isChecked = value;
            NotifyOnPropertyChange("IsChecked");
        }
    }
}

private DelegateCommand checkCommand;
public DelegateCommand CheckCommand
{
    get
    {           
        return checkCommand;
    }
    set
    {
        checkCommand = value;
        NotifyOnPropertyChange("CheckCommand");
    }
}
```

The CheckCommand and IsChecked property are in the model class "Cours" since I had a binding expression error that said that I have to have them there, otherwise the binding will not be correct.The check command takes the method "CheckState" which is encountered in the VM:

```
public void CheckState(object param)
{

   foreach(Cours item in Courses)
   {
        if(item.IsChecked==true)
        {
            SelectedCourses.Add(item);
        }
   }
}
```

All the delegate commands are passed to the constructor in the VM as follows:

```
public RegisterTeacherViewModel
{
    mergeCommand = new DelegateCommand(CreateCrazy);
    saveCommand = new DelegateCommand(SaveTeacher);
    c.CheckCommand = new DelegateCommand(CheckState);
}//as you can notice,this command has a reference to the model
```

class"Cours" where it is actually implemented.

And finally, but not least the view class where I have my binding:

```
<Window x:Class="LastAndFinalVersion.View.Register"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LastAndFinalVersion.ViewModel"
    xmlns:mm="clr-namespace:LastAndFinalVersion.Helpers"
    xmlns:ms="clr-namespace:LastAndFinalVersion.Model"  
    mc:Ignorable="d">

<Window.DataContext>
<local:RegisterTeacherViewModel />

</Window.DataContext>
<Grid Margin="20,20,3.6,28.4">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListBox x:Name="coursesList" SelectedValue="SelectedCourses" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCourse}"  Margin="418,13.2,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="225" Grid.RowSpan="2"  ItemsSource="{Binding Courses,Mode=TwoWay}" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Command="{Binding CheckCommand,Mode=TwoWay}" Content="{Binding Path=courseName}"></CheckBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
<Button Content="Submit" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="517,98.4,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110" Height="40"/>
    <Label Content="Register"                 
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

As fellow programmers, can anyone tell me where is the problem, because I don't see it and still, the program is not working as wanted.Any advice or example will be appreciated.I forgot to mention that I'm using MVVM with DB first.

This is everything is my xaml.cs that is related to both checkbox and listbox:

```
    private void CheckBoxCourses_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       var checkBox = sender as CheckBox;
        if (checkBox != null)
        {
            checkBox.IsChecked = true;
        }
    }

    private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, 
   SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((RegisterTeacherViewModel)DataContext).SelectedCourses.Clear();
        foreach (Cours item in coursesList.SelectedItems)
        {
            ((RegisterTeacherViewModel)DataContext).SelectedCourses.Add(item);
        }
    }

    private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((CheckBox)sender).GetBindingExpression(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty).UpdateTarget();
    }
```

This is the "Cours" class:

```
  using LastAndFinalVersion.Commands;
using LastAndFinalVersion.ViewModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

public partial class Cours:INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Cours()
    {
        this.RegisterTeachers = new ObservableCollection<RegisterTeacher>();
       // RegisterTeacherViewModel rt = new RegisterTeacherViewModel();

         //   IsChecked = true;
    }

    public string courseName { get; set; }
    public int SNTeacher { get; set; }
    public string education { get; set; }
    public string ClassID { get; set; }
    public int courseID { get; set; }
    private bool isChecked;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return isChecked; }
        set
        {
            if(isChecked!=value)
            {
                isChecked = value;
                NotifyOnPropertyChange("IsChecked");
            }
        }
    }
    private DelegateCommand checkCommand;
    public DelegateCommand CheckCommand
    {
        get
        {

            return checkCommand;
        }
        set
        {
            checkCommand = value;
            NotifyOnPropertyChange("CheckCommand");
        }
    }


    public void SelectedItems()
    {
        courseName.Equals(IsChecked);
    }
    protected void NotifyOnPropertyChange(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public virtual RegisterTeacher RegisterTeacher { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ObservableCollection<RegisterTeacher> RegisterTeachers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what do you do in Checked="CheckBox_Checked" ?? if there is a command why have an event ? i am afraid to say that there are more than one issues but show us the event handler, and is there a canexecute for commands that you bind ? infact why have a command with checkbox in first place ?

Comment: I have asked so many people until now and I have tried to do it the way they suggested.I know my code is crowded,but even if i take this part from scratch it will not work for some reason.At the beggining I have binded only the actual values in the view,but then when I saw that it's not working,I started researching and tried everything.

Comment: dont get disheartened, we all have been in this situation, just remove all check commands, and event handlers

Comment: <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"> is enough for your checkbox to work

Comment: also show us Cours class

Comment: Got it @Muds :) And after I remove the check command and event handler,what approach should I use to make it work?

Comment: @Muds now you can also see the 'Cours' class with the mention that I have deleted everything beside the IsChecked value and the normal values .

Comment: explain us what are you trying to do, just requirement wise not code wise

Comment: Now @Muds i did the binding for the checkbox as you told me.For the listbox,should I change something as well?

Comment: explain what are you trying to achieve

Comment: @Muds So I have a combobox with some programs,I click a button and inside the listbox will appear all the courses for that program.Every course has a checkbox so that the lecturer can check the courses and at the end,the courses are stored in a collection for the selected courses only,so when the lecturer saves all the data inserted,he will prefigure in the db teaching the chosen courses.

Comment: so if i understand it right, relation is -- a teacher can have many courses and every course can have many students.. ?

Comment: @Muds that's right.A teacher can have many courses,a course can have multiple teachers,and a course can have multiple students as well as a student can have multiple courses.

Comment: upload your code at git, will look into if i get enough time

Comment: Thank you @Muds for your help.This is the link for the project:https://github.com/faustinaedm/AttendanceListProject.git

Comment: tl;dr two things, observable collection properties should be **read only**. They implement INCC, so there's no need to replace them. Second, use Snoop at runtime to observe your bindings. It's easy to use and can identify issues quickly.